PySCF: Frozen Core FCI calculation
PySCF gives the option to freeze orbitals in CISD calculations by:
myci = ci.CISD(mf, frozen=2).run()

However, for FCI calculations
myfci = fci.FCI(mf, frozen=2).run()

frozen is an unexpected keyword.
How does one freeze selected orbitals? Including how to freeze specific virtual orbitals. For instance, if the frozen argument was:
myci = ci.CISD(mf, frozen=[0,1,4,16,17,18]).run()

for FCI.
Note:

Orbitals 2 and 3 would be active occupied orbitals,
Orbitals 1 and 4 would be frozen occupied orbitals,
Orbitals 16, 17, and 18 would be frozen virtual orbitals.


According to the comment from one of the contributors of PySCF, you can 'do a CASCI calculation setting all orbitals active except the core one' (https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/issues/621#issuecomment-635068463)
